# can't publish a question "This looks like spam."

Tags: discussion, bug

I'm trying to publish this question but I can't as the body is marked with "This looks like spam.". Any idea how I can fix my post? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Might be worth looking at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375108/cant-post-question-on-stack-overflow-this-looks-like-spam and those links. If I had to guess, your block may be due to the number of "stream" words. I happen to have seen a large influx of streaming-related spam recently (on another SE site), so I wonder if there's an SE mechanism that is blocking your post for that reason.

Comment: This has to be a bug. The question is clearly fine: it's clear, detailed, well formatted and everything!

Comment: As a temporary workaround, can you post a stub, and then try and edit the full question in? Alternatively, if you can post this as a gist on github or something and link to it, one of the mods or any high rep user can just copy it into your question. If you do this, please also raise a moderator flag, choose the "needs moderator attention" option and just link us to where you have put the full text of the question so we can edit it for you .

Comment: This reminds me of a similar experience I had way back in 2016.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284812/307622 I bet combination of bad keywords (camera, stream) plus new account result in the block.

Answer (score -3):

My blind guess for a google service would be:
The url fragments and keywords collect too many negative point. Basically what Wildcard commented.

Stackexchange seems to use a similar system.
So...
It physically hurts me to say this but:
Try posting the stuff in code tags as an image.

Comment: Maybe even combine [Luuklag's advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375108/cant-post-question-on-stack-overflow-this-looks-like-spam#comment1249585_375108)  of *"cutting part by part from your post until it works"* and then pasting the remainder as an image?

Comment: ... or changing it so that it does not contain the offending terms, once you know what they are.

Comment: No, please don't post as an image. That really isn't helpful. Just post a stub, and then edit the code in, or flag for mod attention and ask us to add it, but posting an image is really not helpful.